# Open Konsole sessions (tabs) in two distict windows

Tags: shell-script, window, konsole, tabs

I have a script that opens Konsole sessions for me to work with, it looks like:

```
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="k1" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc1
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="k2" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc2
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="k3" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc3
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="k4" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc4
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="k5" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc5
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="k6" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc6
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="k7" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc7
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="k8" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc8

konsole --profile $1 &
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="1s" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc1 sh
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="2s" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc2 sh
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="3s" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc3 sh
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="4s" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc4 sh
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="5s" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc5 sh
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="6s" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc6 sh
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="7s" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc7 sh
konsole --profile $1 --new-tab -p tabtitle="8s" -e ./jpax_remote.sh cc8 sh
```

Now this works fine only that I end up with one window with 16 tabs and I want to have two windows with 8 tabs each (the first block in one window, I then start another Konsole session and I'd want the second block of 8 tabs to be opened  in the new session). How do I get this achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You can control konsole using [dbus scripting](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/scripting.html):

You might use something like this:

```
konsole&sleep 0.1
qdbus org.kde.konsole-$! /Windows/1 newSession
konsole&sleep 0.1
qdbus org.kde.konsole-$! /Windows/1 newSession
```

You can also run commands and set title:

```
konsole&sleep 0.1
id=$(qdbus org.kde.konsole-$! /Windows/1 newSession)
qdbus org.kde.konsole-$! /Sessions/$id setTitle 1 title
qdbus org.kde.konsole-$! /Sessions/$id sendText ls$'\n'
```